# compiler note "I don't know the key /tikz/ ..." is puzzling me

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, packages, axis

could help me to discover my mistake?

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{ Convergence poo on kkk and lkj}
\label{courb1}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=6.35cm,
title={MM(BOOP) },
x unit=m,x unit prefix=k,
y unit=N,y unit prefix=m,
xlabel=Iteration,ylabel=solution quality]

\addplot coordinates {
(60,5421)
(180,87555)
(300,14578)
(420,3698)
(540,1478)
(660,9875)
(780,1236)
(960,5874)
(1000,9876)
};
\addplot coordinates {
(60,7895)
(180,4125)
(300,9875)
(420,6325)
(540,1478)
(660,9874)
(780,1254)
(960,9875)
(1000,1478)
};
\legend{NNA,NNA-MM}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=6.35cm,
title={POO(PLL) },
x unit=m,x unit prefix=k,
y unit=N,y unit prefix=m,
xlabel=Iteration]

\addplot coordinates {
(60,36899)
(180,4587)
(300,14587)
(420,32654)
(540,33493)
(660,14879)
(780,12587)
(960,9865)
(1000,6598)
};
\addplot coordinates {
(60,5444)
(180,5699)
(300,4125)
(420,789)
(540,1487)
(660,31070)
(780,30980)
(960,30910)
(1000,30910)
};
\legend{MLO,MLO-NN}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Could you describe the problem?

Comment: As Bobyandbob says in his/hers answer, there are no problems in your code, so why exactly do you think you have made a mistake?

Comment: when I implement my code, i still have this note: I don't know the key /tikz/y unit prfex', to which you passed 'm' and i am going to ignore.....theis is my problem

Comment: Yes, I just saw your comment on the answer. Did you load the `units` library as in the answer?

Comment: Please post a _complete_ (small) document that makes an error (as in the posted answer) we can not debug the parts that you have not shown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything works, if you use all needed packages... . Or do you have further questions and problems?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{ Convergence NL8 on TTP and UTTP}
\label{courb1}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=6.35cm,
title={MM(BOOP) },
x unit=m,x unit prefix=k,
y unit=N,y unit prefix=m,
xlabel=Iteration,ylabel=solution quality]

\addplot coordinates {
(60,5421)
(180,87555)
(300,14578)
(420,3698)
(540,1478)
(660,9875)
(780,1236)
(960,5874)
(1000,9876)
};
\addplot coordinates {
(60,7895)
(180,4125)
(300,9875)
(420,6325)
(540,1478)
(660,9874)
(780,1254)
(960,9875)
(1000,1478)
};
\legend{BBO,BBO-VNS}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=6.35cm,
title={NL8 (UTTP) },
x unit=m,x unit prefix=k,
y unit=N,y unit prefix=m,
xlabel=Iteration]

\addplot coordinates {
(60,36899)
(180,4587)
(300,14587)
(420,32654)
(540,33493)
(660,14879)
(780,12587)
(960,9865)
(1000,6598)
};
\addplot coordinates {
(60,5444)
(180,5699)
(300,4125)
(420,789)
(540,1487)
(660,31070)
(780,30980)
(960,30910)
(1000,30910)
};
\legend{BBO,BBO-VNS}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know the key /tikz/y unit prfex', to which you passed 'm' and i am going to ignore

Comment: There is no description, on what this answer exactly does differently.